why Firestore set adds 9 reads?
I have this line in Nodejs:
db.collection("foo").doc(fooId).set(fooDtoModified);

If I return before this line, I see a certain amount of reads and writes. If I return right after this line, I see 9 reads and 1 write more. I understand the writing, but what causes the 9 reads?

Writing a document with the code you shared does not cause a read operation on the database, so that's comign from elsewhere. Do you have the Fiebase console open by any chance?

Also important to note that many frameworks might take extra actions like re-rendering from scratch when executed in development mode to help catch issues before pushing to production. Additionally, you might have disabled caching when running your app during development which would cause normally-cached requests to hit the server. These quirks coupled with having the console open (as Puf suggested above) might be some of the reasons for the behaviour you observe.

hello, thanks for the answers @FrankvanPuffelen and samthecodingman, I have the console open on the Usage page. I'll do an other test.

When you're calling set() you're only writing data to Firestore. You're not reading anything. So the shared line of code doesn't cause any read operations in Firestore. As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, the reads are likely to come from other parts of your code, or from the Firebase Console.
From my experience, one of the most known common sources of unexpected reads is indeed the Firebase Console. The console is considered a client like any other web or mobile client. Here are some info:

Firestore - unexpected reads


It was a listener in the application which I did not notice before. But thanks for replying.
